# Paypal Return Variables

Tags: variables, paypal

I am trying to set up a paypal payment for my website. This part is easy. I do however need to have the amount purchased returned to the return URL so I can add it in the database. I have been searching for ages for the answer and can not find it.... please help

Comment: If your issue is resolved. try to add/accept the answer.